# Azure Policy field type

Tags: azure, policy

I want to create a policy where i audit/deny PostgreSQL Databases which do not have firewall rules configured. This is a policy which is workin but the compliance state shows every single rule in it...

```
    {
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/firewallRules"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/firewallRules/startIpAddress",
          "exists": "false"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/firewallRules/endIpAddress",
          "exists": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "The effect determines what happens when the policy rule is evaluated to match"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Audit",
        "Deny",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Audit"
    }
  }
}
```

As soon as I change **Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/firewallRules** to **Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers** it cannot create the policy with error:

> The policy definition '6bab4b2f-30b3-4f07-a92e-496b6309d14d' targets multiple resource types, but the policy rule is authored in a way that makes the policy not applicable to the target resource types 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers,Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/firewallRules'. This is because the policy rule has a condition that can never be satisfied by the target resource types. If an alias is used, please make sure that the alias gets evaluated against only the resource type it belongs to by adding a type condition before it, or split the policy into multiple ones to avoid targeting multiple resource types.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?